# Update value after loading xml file

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

i am loading the following xml file using the `readUrl` command

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <a>
         <b>xyz</b>
         <c>
            <d>false</d>
            <e>false</e>
            <f>true</f>
         </c>
      </a>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

in the same dataweave as the readUrl command - i would like to update the xml `e` value from `false` to `true`

can someone please assist

cheers,

jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the update operator available in Mule 4.3.0 can be used to update the value as required:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns soapenv http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
var soapMessage=readUrl("...","application/xml")
---
soapMessage update {
        case .soapenv#Envelope.soapenv#Body.a.c.e -> true
}
```